Merge touching polygons within sf dataframe or terra spatvector in R
I have a list of vector polygons in terra, some are separate and distinct, some are touching. Usually, the touching ones are- in reality- all part of the same shape, but are split in this way because different sections were added on in different years, etc.
I need to programmatically combine the ones that are touching, but not all of them are, and sometimes many touch consecutively, end-to-end.
I think there should be a way to do this with relate() and combineGeoms() or similar, but I can't figure out how to do it other than with manual editing of each shape group. Seems like this should be a doable task for large and complex shapefiles.
Also open to a solution using sf, I don't mind either way.
What I want is a function with which I can use the relation matrix to merge all shapes that touch within groups, resulting in a vector dataframe with fewer rows because separate touching shapes will dissolve into one. In this case, the dataset would go from 7 polygons to 4.
Minimal reprex below:

library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Define a function to create a simple square polygon
create_square <- function(x_center, y_center, size) {
  half_size <- size / 2
  st_polygon(list(matrix(c(
    x_center - half_size, y_center - half_size,
    x_center + half_size, y_center - half_size,
    x_center + half_size, y_center + half_size,
    x_center - half_size, y_center + half_size,
    x_center - half_size, y_center - half_size
  ), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)))
}

# Create individual shapes
shape1 <- create_square(1, 1, 1)
shape2 <- create_square(4, 1, 1)
shape3 <- create_square(6, 1, 1)
shape4 <- create_square(7, 1, 1)
shape5 <- create_square(7.5, 2, 1)
shape6 <- create_square(2.5, 2.5,1)
shape7 <- create_square(2, 3.5, 1)

# Combine shapes into an sf object
shapes <- st_sf(
  geometry = st_sfc(
    shape1,
    shape2,
    shape3,
    shape4,
    shape5,
    shape6,
    shape7
  )
) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste0("shape_",c(1:nrow(.)))) %>%
  relocate(name)

# Define a coordinate reference system (CRS), for example, EPSG:4326 (WGS84)
crs <- st_crs(4326)
st_crs(shapes) <- crs

# plot
shapes %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = name))

# convert to spatvector 
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
shapes_vect <- vect(shapes)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = shapes_vect,
                  aes(fill = name))

# make relation matrix of touching shapes
relate(shapes_vect,
       shapes_vect,
       relation = "touches")

# manually combine shapes 3,4,5
test <- combineGeoms(shapes_vect[3,],
                     shapes_vect[5,]) %>%
  combineGeoms(shapes_vect[4,])

# create new dataframe with the combined shape
# instead of 3,4,5 individually
shapes_new <- shapes_vect[c(1:2, 6:7),] %>%
  rbind(test)

# plot again
ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = shapes_new,
                  aes(fill = name)) 



dplyr::summarise() combined with sf::st_union() will achieve your desired outcome. Note that applying some sf functions to non-projected data e.g. WGS84/EPSG:4326, can result in unwanted artifacts.
To get around this, your can first project your data, then change it back to the original CRS once the polygons are merged. In this example, I have use WGS84 Pseudo Mercator/EPSG:3857 for this purpose.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Project shapes, merge contiguous polygons, st_cast() to individual polygons,
# change back to original CRS, assign unique id
sf_poly <- shapes |>
  st_transform(3857) |>
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) |>
  st_cast("POLYGON") |>
  st_transform(4326)

sf_poly
# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0.5 ymin: 0.5 xmax: 8 ymax: 4
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#                         geometry id
# 1 POLYGON ((1.5 1.5, 1.5 0.5,...  1
# 2 POLYGON ((4.5 0.5, 3.5 0.5,...  2
# 3 POLYGON ((5.5 0.5, 5.5 1.5,...  3
# 4 POLYGON ((2 2, 2 3, 1.5 3, ...  4

Because you do not have a grouping variable, it makes sense to assign a group variable back to your individual polygons in your shapes sf rather than assigning multiple id values to a single (merged) polygon. In this reprex, I have created the id column for this purpose. Having an id column will allow you to run analysis by group. An example workflow is shown below:
# Spatially join group id values to shapes
shapes1 <- st_join(shapes, sf_poly)

shapes1
# Simple feature collection with 7 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0.5 ymin: 0.5 xmax: 8 ymax: 4
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#      name id                       geometry
# 1 shape_1  1 POLYGON ((0.5 0.5, 1.5 0.5,...
# 2 shape_2  2 POLYGON ((3.5 0.5, 4.5 0.5,...
# 3 shape_3  3 POLYGON ((5.5 0.5, 6.5 0.5,...
# 4 shape_4  3 POLYGON ((6.5 0.5, 7.5 0.5,...
# 5 shape_5  3 POLYGON ((7 1.5, 8 1.5, 8 2...
# 6 shape_6  4 POLYGON ((2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 2 ...
# 7 shape_7  4 POLYGON ((1.5 3, 2.5 3, 2.5...

# Add example variable to shapes1 for illustrative purposes
set.seed(1)
shapes1$values <- runif(7, min = 0, max = 1)

# Return mean values per id group
shapes1 |>
  summarise(mean_values = mean(values), .by = id, across(geometry, st_union))
# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 0.5 ymin: 0.5 xmax: 8 ymax: 4
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#   id mean_values                       geometry
# 1  1   0.2655087 POLYGON ((0.5 0.5, 1.5 0.5,...
# 2  2   0.3721239 POLYGON ((3.5 0.5, 4.5 0.5,...
# 3  3   0.5609144 POLYGON ((6.5 1.5, 5.5 1.5,...
# 4  4   0.9215325 POLYGON ((1.5 3, 2.25 3.000...

In short, it's likely easier to keep your polygons separate, but assign them a group value. If necessary, you can then join grouped data back to your original data.

Hmm, yes, in this case, this fix works. However, by flattening the entire dataset into one multipolygon then casting back out into individual polygons, we lose all the info about each original row (e.g., "name" here, but more in the real dataset), and in the real dataset, some shapes are correctly multipolygons. I think I need to somehow group_by() first using criteria about which shapes touch each other so that I can maintain the extra information when I summarize. Any ideas?

@JakeL - based on your example data, group_by() won't work as there are no groups, only unique names. If you need to retain information from the original polygons, update your question with what information you want to retain and a more representative dataset if necessary. There will be a solution.

Well, there is not a grouping variable, that's why I am trying to find a way to programmatically assign groups based on which shapes are touching each other, while leaving the rest of the shapes alone. But I still want to maintain the info from the grouped sites (in this case, for example, the name). I think I have found a solution using igraph. Will update tomorrow if I have time to clean it up.

@JakeL - answer updated with a suggested workflow that will allow you to keep track of which polygons correspond to each merged polygon. The answer update goes as far as creating example summary values per merged polygon. If it serves your analysis, you can then join this data back to your original polygons using either a spatial join,, or something like a left  join by id values. Let me know if this suits your intended workflow.

You can use terra::aggregate followed by terra::disagg,
library(terra)
v <- vect(shapes)
v$ID <- 1:nrow(v)
x <- aggregate(v) |> disagg()
plot(x, col=rainbow(4))

You can get the relation between the new and old polygons like this
relate(centroids(v, inside=TRUE), x, "intersects", pairs=TRUE)
#     id.x id.y
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    3    3
#[4,]    4    3
#[5,]    5    3
#[6,]    6    4
#[7,]    7    4

